# java ide applet

Tags: java, ide, applet

I'd like to be able to graphically design java web applets like you can do with standard desktop java programs in netbeans...but I can't seem to be able to do that in netbeans. Any ideas on programs, or maybe I'm not doing it right in netbeans. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Add new file, Swing gui forms, jApplet